# Notification from a service works, but the activity is not started

Tags: android-layout, android-emulator, android-service, android

I'm trying to send a notification from a service, and does that succeessfully (the notification does show on the status bar).
BUT, after the click on the notification in order to watch the activity - I'm going back to the mobile home screen. In addition, I've noticed in debug mode that i'm not reaching to the activity's "onCreate" method.

here is my piece of code:
The service code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int icon = R.drawable.notificationicon;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, NotificationsActivity.class), 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "My notification","Hello World!", pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Activity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(dialogLayout);
}
```

Comment: Is the NotificationActivity class well defined in the AndroidManifest.xml? (can you paste your AndroidManifest?)

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to `startActivity` from within a receiver / service, you must create an intent, add a flag notifying it to start a new task and THEN start the activity.

adapt this pseudo-code:

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, com.myCorp.myApp.myClass.class);
startServiceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(startServiceIntent);
```

i use this in a BootReceiver to start up an application ([for example use this BootReceiver](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html)).